# How to remove duplicate values in control panel?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, duplicates, control-panel

I have created an application **MyApp** . I can install **MyApp** directly using its setup, then i can see **MyApp** in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features .

Along with it I have created an installer (**MyApp Installer**) using inno setup for **MyApp** .when i install it using the installer ,Both **MyApp** and **MyApp Installer** are visible in control panel. It may confuse the user while uninstalling it .So I want only one (**MyApp Installer**) to be appeared in control panel .

How can I hide **MyApp** in control panel and show only **MyApp Installer** when i install it through inno setup installer ?

Comment: Set the [`CreateUninstallRegKey`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createuninstallregkey) directive value to `no`.

Comment: @TLama ,Thank you , It will hide entry of my Installer name in Control Panel ,If I want to hide entry of MyApp and show MyAppInstaller then ?

Comment: No, that directive doesn't hide anything. It just won't create an entry for the current setup there. Or do you really need to hide an entry from there for an existing, already installed application ?

Comment: yes I want to hide the existing application .Because however its existance is represented by the entry of the installer in control panel.